# How to download multiple offline map databases with MBXMapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I would like to download multiple offline map databases using MBXMapKit. This is more a Objective-C problem than a MBXMapKit library problem.

I would like to do something like this:

```
for ( DestinationObject *dest in self.dest ) {
    //Put the map to the right position
    [self centerMapWithDest:dest];
    [[MBXOfflineMapDownloader sharedOfflineMapDownloader] beginDownloadingMapID:_rasterOverlay.mapID mapRegion:_mapView.region minimumZ:_rasterOverlay.minimumZ maximumZ:MIN(16,_rasterOverlay.maximumZ)];
}
```

and here the delegate function:

```
-(void)offlineMapDownloader:(MBXOfflineMapDownloader *)offlineMapDownloader didCompleteOfflineMapDatabase:
```

I know this is not possible like this because the library crashes after the second call because the first part is not finished yet.
But how to call the next download when the first one is finished ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mbxmapkit/api/Protocols/MBXOfflineMapDownloaderDelegate.html), you want to use the `MBXOfflineMapDownloaderDelegate` protocol to know when a download completes/fails out before starting the next one, since the downloaded class can only handle one download at a time.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. For now I use an array with all the regions I want, and call my download function each time a map is completed until the array is empty. I don't know if it's the best way, but it works.